# ADD EXCEL DATA TO Multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, excel, multidimensional-array

I am straggling with multidimensional ArrayLists.
I'm reading data from a excel file with 3 rows ID, Date, and INFO.
I managed to set the arrayList but with the 3rows data in each index
i.e array (1) id1 date1 info1. Can not call info1 individually.
I need to create a multy. arraylist where I can call arrayindex(1) item info1.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String xx;

String show;
int count=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
    public void order(View v) {
        try {
            AssetManager am=getAssets();
            InputStream is=am.open("test.xls");
            Workbook wb =Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
            Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);
            int row =s.getRows();
            int col=s.getColumns();
            xx="";
            for(int i=0; i<row ; i++)
            {
                for (int c=0; c<col; c++)
                {
                    Cell z=s.getCell(c,i);
                    xx=xx+z.getContents();
                    xx=xx+"  ";
                        mainArray();

                }
                xx=xx+"\n";
            }

            display(xx);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
public void display(String value)
{
    TextView x=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    x.setText(value);


}
public void mainArray() {

    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();



    arrayList.add(xx);
    Log.d("log1","Size of al after additions: " + arrayList.size());


    Log.d("log1","Contents of al: " + arrayList);

}
```

}

How to initiate a multidimensional arraylist(id, date, info) and how on iteration I can append depending on row/line, the data in the proper list.

```
ArrayList
    [
     list_Id {id1, id2,id3,.............}
     list_Date {date1, date2,date3.......}
     list_Info {info1, info2, info3.......}
    ]
```

Comment: You should not use id, date, info as seperate Lists. You should use one List with pojo's which stores the thre values for a row

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer is the approach you need to follow - break every problem to a smaller problems and try to resolve those one by one.

Here it seems to me, you are trying to do 2 things - reading data from excel, converting the data to "multidimensional ArrayLists" and now you do not know what is not working...

Please, try to print the data from excel first to a console - you will verify, your reading part is working.

---

Why you want to have "multidimensional ArrayLists"? You have rows and cols, so can you start with `String[][] table = new String[rows][cols];` ?

---

There are several problems in your code - String xx shouldn't be there, but it's just a temporary I'd say.

Never ever ignore exception - how you want to know there was exception, at least log something!

Answer (score 0):

```
///////////****** WRITE Excel TO SD ***/////////////
    Fnamexls="testfile"  + ".xls";
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/My File");
    directory.mkdirs();
    sdFile = new File(directory, Fnamexls);
    if(sdFile.exists()) {
//Do something
        Log.d("logW","exixts");
    }
    else {
// Do something else.
        Log.d("logW", "does not exixt");
        wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
        try {
            wrWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(sdFile, wbSettings);
            writeSheet = wrWorkbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
            int row = s.getRows();
            int col = s.getColumns();
            xx = "";
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
                    Cell z = s.getCell(c, r);
                    xx = z.getContents();
                    Label label4 = new Label(c, r, String.valueOf(xx));
                    try {
                        writeSheet.addCell(label4);
                    } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (WriteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            wrWorkbook.write();
            try {
                wrWorkbook.close();
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //createExcel(excelSheet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    readSD();
```